# CreateProcess does not return extected value

Tags: visual-c++

I want to send the double quote character to my CreateProcess function. How can I do the correct way? I want to send all of this characters:  "%h"

```
CreateProcess(L"C:\\identify -format ",L"\"%h\" trustedsnapshot.png",0,0,TRUE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_NO_WINDOW,0,0,&sInfo,&pInfo);
```

note: "identify" is an Imagemagick program.

Here is the full code:

```
int ExecuteExternalFile()     
{ 
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secattr; 
ZeroMemory(&secattr,sizeof(secattr));
secattr.nLength = sizeof(secattr);
secattr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

HANDLE rPipe, wPipe;

//Create pipes to write and read data

CreatePipe(&rPipe,&wPipe,&secattr,0);

STARTUPINFO sInfo; 
ZeroMemory(&sInfo,sizeof(sInfo));
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo; 
ZeroMemory(&pInfo,sizeof(pInfo));
sInfo.cb=sizeof(sInfo);
sInfo.dwFlags=STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
sInfo.hStdInput=NULL; 
sInfo.hStdOutput=wPipe; 
sInfo.hStdError=wPipe;

CreateProcess(L"C:\\identify",L" -format \"%h\" trustedsnapshot.png",0,0,TRUE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_NO_WINDOW,0,0,&sInfo,&pInfo);



CloseHandle(wPipe);

char buf[100];
DWORD reDword; 
CString m_csOutput,csTemp;
BOOL res;
do
{
  res=::ReadFile(rPipe,buf,100,&reDword,0);
  csTemp=buf;
  m_csOutput+=csTemp.Left(reDword);
}while(res);

//return m_csOutput;
float fvar; 
//fvar = atof((const char *)(LPCTSTR)(m_csOutput));  ori


//fvar=atof((LPCTSTR)m_csOutput);
fvar = _tstof(m_csOutput);

const size_t len = 256;
wchar_t buffer[len] = {};
_snwprintf(buffer, len - 1, L"%d", fvar);


MessageBox(NULL, buffer, L"test print createprocess value", MB_OK);

return fvar;
}
```

I need this function to return the integer value from the CreateProcess.

Comment: it works now. I just realized that the executables need to put *.exe at the end of its name. So for this case :   identify.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it should work OK, or do you have any problems with it?

Comment: My project can compile, but it seems does not return the value I expected when I dump it to a Messagebox. The output should be an integer.

Comment: I just noticed - why are you passing -format in the first parameter? In it you should pass only path to executable, i.e. "C:\identify

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the quotes.   There are two problems with the way you pass parameters to CreateProcess.  The first is that the command line passed in the second argument should include the name of the command (that is, it should include the value for "argv[0]"),  the second is that the redirection (> testt.txt) is not handled by the CreateProcess API,.  Unless c:\identify expects such arguemnts, you should not include this in the command line.

Comment: I has throw away that part. When I run "identify -format "%h" currentsnapshot.png" at windows command terminal it work. But when run from inside CreateProcess it does not work.

Comment: Try CreateProcess(NULL, L"identify -format \"%h\" trustedsnapshot.png",0,0,TRUE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_NO_WINDOW,0,0,&sInfo,&pInfo);